# Angular-carousel is not working in a safari browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have integrated Angular carousal in my project it's working fine in all browser except the Safari.

I have taken reference from [angular-carousel](http://kuus.github.io/angular-carousel/).

i did in my project

in index.html i have included below files:

```
<script src="js/carousel/angular-swipe.js"></script>
    <script src="js/carousel/angular-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="client/html/carouselController.js"></script>

<div class="row" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ul class="my-slider" rn-carousel rn-carousel-buffered rn-carousel-indicator rn-carousel-control>
                  <li ng-repeat="slide in slides|limitTo:5" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + slide.img + ')'}">
                    <div class="debug">
                      {{ slide.label }} / {{ slides.length }}
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

in app.js

```
var app = angular.module("demoApp",
["ngRoute", "ngSanitize", "ngResource", "ui.bootstrap",
 "angularMoment", "blockUI",'facebook','directive.g+signin',
 "angular-carousel","swipe"
 ]);
```

and also added controller of the given reference.

How can i support it in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm use jquery.carouFredSel.js for Angular apps

For example, in directive

```js
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: [ "$scope", function($scope) {
          var slides = $scope.slides = [];
          // Add slides here 
           slides.push({
              image: '',
              alt: ''
             }); 
        }],    
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
             $scope.$watch('mycarousel', function() {

// this jquery.carouFredSel.js example setup begin  
$('#mycarousel').carouFredSel({
  width: '100%',
  items: {
   visible: 'odd+2'
  },
  scroll: {
   pauseOnHover: true,
   onBefore: function() {
    $(this).children().removeClass( 'hover' );
   }
  },
  auto: {
   items: 1,
   easing: 'linear',
   duration: 1250,
   timeoutDuration: 0
  },
  pagination: {
   container: '#pager',
   items: 1,
   duration: 0.5,
   queue: 'last',
   onAfter: function() {
    var cur = $(this).triggerHandler( 'currentVisible' ),
     mid = Math.floor( cur.length / 2 );
 
    cur.eq( mid ).addClass( 'hover' );
   }
  }
 });
    // setup carousel end

             })
            },
```

In HTML template

```html
<div id="wrapper"><div id="mycarousel">
                <div ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                  <a href="#"><img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" alt="{{slide.alt}}" width="200" height="200" /></a>
                  <span>{{slide.alt}}</span>
                </div>
                </div><div id="pager">
</div></div>
```